# Rsync full backup --exclude option not working

Tags: 14.04, backup, cron, rsync

I run the following command as sudo everything works fine:

```
rsync -aAXv --delete --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found",”/home/*/.thumbnails/*”,”/home/*/.cache/google-chrome/*”,”/home/*/.local/share/Trash/*”,”/home/*/.gvfs”} /* /mnt/JUKEBOX/Backup/LANbox
```

If I try running it as root either from cron or from a script it wants to ignore everything I have excluded in the command and backup everything from /mnt creating an infinite loop until the disk runs out of space. All I want to know is WHY? I then created a script to be run as root that excludes each directory manually which works but its so long I can't copy and paste it hence the script:

```
rsync -aAXv --delete --exclude '/dev/*' --exclude '/proc/*' --exclude '/sys/*' --exclude '/tmp/*' --exclude '/run/*' --exclude '/mnt/*' --exclude '/media/*' --exclude '/lost+found' --exclude '/home/*/.thumbnails/*' --exclude '/home/*/.cache/google-chrome/*' --exclude '/home/*/.local/share/Trash/*' --exclude '/home/*/.gvfs' /* /mnt/JUKEBOX/Backup/LANbox >> /var/log/backup.log
```

Just would like to know why I have to manually exclude things?

Comment: Just a tip, you can use `--exclude-from=filename` where `filename` contains the directories in separate lines. This will make it much easier if you ever wanted to add/remove from the exclude list.

Comment: Yes that would work as well I would just worry about it ignoring that too and once again filling up my drive.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some very funky quotes in your exclude line. Some are normal `"` quotes, and others are `”` quotes. I'd try to make everything one type of quote (preferably the former) and let us know if that helps.